# CentOS won't boot on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, boot, centos6.4

I installed CentOS 6 on Virtual Box. After the install it starts up and I select *boot from local disk*. When I do this, it goes to a black screen that says

```
Booting from local disk...
FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE
```

The CentOS version is 6.4-x86_64-minimal and Virtual Box is updated to the latest version 4.2.18. Any ideas how to make it boot?

*Edit*

I went through the installation process multiple times to verify the installer *wrote to disk* during the installation. It seems pretty straightforward that *boot from disk* should work, but not w/ CentOS, my favorite distro...

Also, I have googled around some, but the only thing out there is people saying, get a different install medium, pretty lame, maybe I'll have to break down and install the server w/ the UI so that I can boot from disk...

Comment: Down votes are lame without comments. CentOS is weak, I have no problem installing Linux with other distros, only CentOS... #hateredhat

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but if you mouseover the downvote button, you'll see the popup "*This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful*". Downvotes without a given reason may be assumed to be for that one.

Comment: Obviously I googled around a bit before asking.., but I'll to more research on my end ...

Comment: That is not obvious.  If you don't tell us what you already did, you risk us wasting our time re-treading ground already trodden; it's impolite to fob off onto others work you could do yourself, especially if you're asking for their help.  I should also warn you that your question is accumulating close votes (one of which **is** mine) because VirtualBox is generally felt to be sub-production quality around here, a classic sign of a question not related to production sysadmin, and therefore off-topic.  Writing more about what you're doing might avoid that, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eject the installation disc, then boot up again.

Comment: Although, frankly, why it can't boot from disk through the installation CD menu is pretty bad.

Comment: It's a bug in VirtualBox, 5 years old too: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2680